# Writing to the serial port in Vista from Python

Tags: python, windows

How do I write to the serial port in Vista from Python? The termios package only seem to support posix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like it wasn't any harder than this using [pyserial](http://pyserial.wiki.sourceforge.net/pySerial):

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port with 9600,8,N,1
print ser.portstr       # check which port was really used
ser.write('hello')
ser.close()
```

Comment: Update your original question if you have new information instead of posting a new answer.  :)

Comment: @Robert P: I disagree, this is more appropriate as an answer

Answer (score 9):

[pyserial](http://pyserial.wiki.sourceforge.net/pySerial) does the trick, you'll need [python extensions for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) for it to work in windows.